# jquery - select text from second a-tag

Tags: jquery

I need help with a (I believe) pretty simple selector. This is the HTML:

```
<a href="http://localhost/index.php?action=profile;u=3" target="_blank"> 
    <img src="http://localhost/index.php?action=dlattach;attach=44;type=avatar" alt="" style="max-width: 16px; max-height: 16px; vertical-align: middle;">
</a>
<a href="http://localhost/index.php?action=profile;u=3" target="_blank" style="color:#8c121a">profilename</a>
```

What I'm doing is to capture clicks on the img-tag and then I want to get the "profilename" text from the 2nd a-tag.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `parent().next().text()`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try simply like this-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').click(function(){
        var text = $(this).parent('a').next('a').html();
        // play with text
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('click', 'img', function(event) {
    var text = $(this).parent().next().text();
    alert(text);
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: @mplungjan why don't you post your answer, so saturnusringar can mark it as the correct answer, I'll remove mine. No issues